# Kentico transformation - Hide field if empty

Tags: transformation, kentico

I have a transformation with a url link that is working, but need to hide the field, if empty. If there is no catalog link, how can I hide this? Should I use a String.IsNullOrEmpty? If so, exactly how do I write it as a url link?

```
<div><p><strong>View <a href="<%# Eval("CatalogURL") %>" target="_blank"> Pathway for this Program</a>.</strong></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking up the Transformation Methods available on the documentation [here](https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods#ReferenceTransformationmethods-Booleanoperations).

You will probably want to do something like:

```
<%# IfEmpty(Eval("CatalogURL"), "", string.Format("<div><p><strong>View <a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\"> Pathway for this Program</a>.</strong></p></div>", Eval("CatalogURL"))) %>
```